# Read a binary file and print its content (Web Server)

Tags: c++, webserver, binaryfiles

i am working on a web server
and i have created a function which sends the file and the http headers
when accessing the http://127.0.0.1:8080 page

the problem is that its not copyig the file correctly.. its throwing some grabage at the end.. (i am trying to pass a binary files thats why im using std::ios::binary)
example.bin

```
My Example bin file
:)
```

Downloaded file:

```
My Example bin file
:)ýýýýÝÝÝÝÝÝÝhjß/ÝÝ
```

my code:

```
// download file http headers
message_ = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
            "Cache-Control: public\r\n"
            "Content-Description: File Transfer\r\n"
            "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.bin\r\n"
            "Content-Type: application/zip\r\n"
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n";

std::filebuf *pbuf;
std::ifstream sourcestr;
long size;
char * buffer;

sourcestr.open("example.bin",std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
pbuf=sourcestr.rdbuf();

size=pbuf->pubseekoff (0,std::ios::end,std::ios::in);
pbuf->pubseekpos (0,std::ios::in);

buffer=new char[size];

// get file data  
pbuf->sgetn (buffer,size);

message_ += buffer;
```

Comment: If you are on a system with a `sendfile` system call (like Linux) then maybe you could use that to send the actual file data?

Comment: i'm using windows not linux.. that garbage at the end of the file drives me crazy :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `buffer` is not null-terminated after the 'pbuf->sgetn()' call. Try:

```
// EDIT: this won't work for reason stated by @Joachim in his answer.
buffer = new char[size + 1];
pbuf->sgetn(buffer, size);
*(buffer + size) = 0;

message_ += buffer;
```

If `message_` is a `std::string` an alternative without NULL termination would be:

```
message_.append(buffer, size);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem is that you are appending the contents of a binary buffer to a string. A string in C++ is terminated by the character '\0', which means that if the binary file contains that character in the middle, the "string" will be terminated. And if the binary file does not contain any '\0' character, appending it to a string will append memory until the terminator is found, which is the reason you get extra garbage. The line `message_ += buffer` simply means to add the memory pointed to by `buffer` until string terminator is found.

You must send a file in two parts: First the header, then the file data.